# How to add item to list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a list in prolog that contains several items. I need to 'normalized' the content of this list and write the result to a new list. But I still have problem in doing it.
The  following code shows how I did it:

```
 normalizeLists(SourceList, DestList) :-

 % get all the member of the source list, one by one
 member(Item, SourceList),

 % normalize the item
 normalizeItem(Item, NormItem),

 % add the normalize Item to the Destination List (it was set [] at beginning)
 append(NormItem, DestList, DestList).
```

The problem is in the append predicate. I guess it is because in prolog, I cannot do something like in imperative programming, such as:

DestList = DestList + NormItem,

But how can I do something like that in Prolog? Or if my approach is incorrect, how can I write prolog code to solve this kind of problem.

Any help is really appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in Prolog cannot be modified, once bound by *unification*. That is a variable is either *free* or has a definite value (a term, could be another variable). Then `append(NormItem, DestList, DestList)` will fail for any `NormItem` that it's not an empty list.

Another problem it's that `NormItem` it's not a list at all. You can try

```
normalizeLists([], []).
normalizeLists([Item|Rest], [NormItem|NormRest]) :-

 % normalize the item
 normalizeItem(Item, NormItem),

 normalizeLists(Rest, NormRest).
```

or (if your Prolog support it) skip altogether such definition, and use an higher order predicate, like maplist

```
...
maplist(normalizeItem, Items, Normalized),
...
```

Comment: Hi CapelliC. It works correctly. Thanks. BTW, yes my prolog support maplist. Can you share a bit more information about how to do it in maplist? Thanks

Comment: I tried the maplist (by just trying of your suggestion) and it works amazingly. Reduce unnecessary code. Thanks